# React con Javascript y Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Muy buenas a todos!

Actualmente trabajo en un proyecto con react creo que fue creado con npx create-react-app name_project hace dos años. Mi pregunta es si se puede añadir el compilador de typescript a este proyecto con el objetivo de añadir nuevos archivos tipo .tsx a los ya existentes sin modificar los originales.

De antemano, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Todo Javascript válido es Typescript válido, así que podrías añadir ficheros TS y renombrar los existentes de JS a TS sin problemas

Comment: Renombrar más de 50 ficheros jsx o js a tsx va a llevar su trabajo. Existe alguna forma de añadir algo como esto: npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript al proyecto ya creado? Gracias por contestar @PabloLozano

Comment: Si estás en un sistema POSIX, puedes usar el comando `for f in **/*.jsx; do mv -- "$f" "${f%.jsx}.tsx"; done` en la raíz de tu proyecto. Esto modificará la extensión de todos los archivos locales `.jsx` a `.tsx` dentro del contexto del directorio de raíz.